# Select Distinct on subset of columns, name different set of columns to return

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and have two tables:

```
Table_A
colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | colF | colG | colH | colI | colJ

Table_B
colA | colB | colC | columnD | colE | columnF | colG | colH | colI | colJ
```

I am trying to insert a number of rows from `table_B` into `table_A`. My problem is that `Table_A` has a primary key based on `colA, colB, colC, colD, and colE`. `Table_B` does not have this restriction, which means a simple `insert` won't work:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF, colG, colH, colI, colJ) 
SELECT colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE, columnF, colG, colH, colI, colJ FROM Table_B;
```

I am trying to work around this by using `DISTINCT` in my selection from `Table_B`. However, I cannot determine the correct syntax to both `select distinct` on the 5 primary key columns used in `Table_A`, and select all ten columns to be inserted. I have tried

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE) 
SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE FROM Table_B;
```

Which correctly pulls unique entries but does not populate columns F-J, and I have tried

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF, colG, colH, colI, colJ) 
SELECT DISTINCT(colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE) colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE, columnF, colG, colH, colI, colJ FROM Table_B;
```

But this fails, as the first column entry is a wrapped version of the 5 unique columns, and fails the insert due to column length restrictions - the `SELECT DISTINCT` in parens returns '' which obviously doesn't fit:

> ERROR: Value is too long for type character varying(12)

My goal would be form a query which gets all the unique combinations of `colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE` from `Table_B`, and inserts those full rows, including `columnF, colG, colH, colI, colJ` into `Table_A`.

Comment: What the criterion should be for selecting one row (from the many that have the same unique key)?

Comment: I don't know that I care - I just need at least one valid record. but is there a way to choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. `SELECT DISTINCT` returns that group of columns, as you've found out. If you use `DISTINCT ON` instead though, you'll get the rows you're looking for.

```
INSERT INTO Table_A 
    (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF, colG, colH, colI, colJ) 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE) 
    colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE, columnF, colG, colH, colI, colJ 
FROM
    Table_B
```

As pointed out by ypercube and in the [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html), you can improve this query by adding `ORDER BY`. Without it, it seems that the choice between two conflicting rows is unpredictable.

```
INSERT INTO Table_A 
    (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF, colG, colH, colI, colJ) 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE) 
    colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE, columnF, colG, colH, colI, colJ 
FROM
    Table_B
ORDER BY
    colA, colB, colC, columnD, colE    -- needed as it is
--  , colX, colY                       -- to choose which row to pick
  ;
```

Comment: If Tom cares about order, yea, then 'order by' would be important, but if they just wants the first entry for whatever reason, I think this would work.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realize I was that close! This totally works (and the ORDER BY is neat, but unnecessary for what I need)

Comment: @ypercube strange, I just tested this in Postgres and `order by` wasn't required.

Comment: @ypercube that's definitely not true. I ran the query in postgres just now to confirm, and it ran successfully without order by.

Comment: @ypercube - Trying to clarify what's in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html), it says that, "Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first."

Comment: Yes my bad, sorry. If there is an order by, the first columns must match the columns of the `distinct on`, this is the restriction.

Comment: I think it is useful for Tom to have `order by` to sort rather than prevent a random selection between multiple rows. There probably aren't many cases where you want it to choose randomly! I edited the post to reflect that.